# Pointless edits

Tags: support, edits

On this question:

[Bukkit API How to set material data to an itemstack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31602685/bukkit-api-how-to-set-material-data-to-an-itemstack)

Someone has edited this post without any revision and all this person edited was changing lowercase letters to capital letters:

google > Google : spigot > Spigot : stackoverflow > Stackoverflow

My question: Why doesn't SO require more than three characters to be changed on an edit

Comment: Why does it matter if it's not going through the review queue? It doesn't waste anyone's time except the editor, and it does make the question *slightly* better. If it were going through the review queue, then maybe - as it wastes peoples time.

Comment: The edit isn't wrong. However, there's more that could be improved.

Comment: Contrary to the comments above, it _was_ a totally pointless edit, "I searched [site], [site] and [site]" is irrelevant and that sentence should have been removed entirely instead of being "fixed".

Answer (score 3):

The character limit is only for those who go through the approval process (users that have less than 2000 reputation). Those who have more than 2000 reputation don't have such limits.